# Generic Resolver Guard in Angular

Tags: angular, guard, resolver

Is it possible to create a generic Resolver Guard in Angular?
I am tried the following:

```
export class BaseResolver <E extends BaseEntity, S extends BaseService> implements Resolve<E> {
      constructor(private service: S, private router: Router) {}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
        Observable<E> {

        let id = route.paramMap.get('id');

        return this.service.getItem(id).pipe(
          take(1),
          map(item => {
            if (item) {
              return item;
            } else { // id not found
              this.router.navigate([this.service.getUrl()]);
              return null;
            }
          })
        );
      }
```

I get compilation errors when trying to configure the router

(User implements BaseEntity Interface)

```
resolve: {
              user: BaseResolver<User, UserService>
            }
```

The error isL

```
Type 'Observable<BaseEntity>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<E>'.
  Type 'BaseEntity' is not assignable to type 'E'
```

Comment: You should call the this.service inside the resolve method. resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
 let id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.service.getItem(id);
  }

Comment: This is the way I implemented, but I get compilation error as described. See edited code.

Answer (score 0):

The `resolve` method should return the same type of object defined in the Resolve interface.

**Resolve interface definition:-**

```
interface Resolve<T> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T
}
```

**Solution 1:-**

If you would like to have specific type, please define a base abstract class, extend with different classes and return the class from resolve method.

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoResolver implements Resolve<BaseEntity> {
  constructor(private service: SomeService, private router: Router) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<ChildBaseEntity> {

    let id = route.paramMap.get('id');    
    return this.service.somemethod('id');    
  }
}


export abstract class BaseEntity {};

export class ChildBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {};
```

**Solution 2:-**

The simple solution would be to change the type of the resolve method to `Observable<any>`.

I am not sure whether the solution 2 would be acceptable for you as you are expecting some type safety.